# file could not be saved, because the source file could not be read. Try again later, or contact the server administrator

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, httpresponse

I have the below code in my library and access that method using WCF service to exporting the saved bitmap image and it stored it project location using “HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath”. Image is saved in that location successfully but I can’t able to open the same file using HttpResponse? I got the following exception

Note: HttpResponse is sending from WCF to library method.

> C:\Users\Username~1.SYN\AppData\Local\Temp\32quwNBj.bmp.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read. Try again later, or contact the server administrator.

```
            System.Web.HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            Bitmap Bitmap = this.GetBitMapImage("Bitmap+path");
            fileName += ".png";
            filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(filePath))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            bitmap.Save(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.ContentType = "image/" + exportMode;
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            response.TransmitFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, fileName));
            //response.WriteFile(filePath + "\\" + fileName);
            reso
            response.Flush();
            response.Close();
```

Comment: It seems firefox issue, tried in chrome or IE?

Comment: No its same problem in both browser.

Comment: Install firefox 38 will solve problem. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1085094. So you can close this issue.!